Solving for a single Eigenvalue
Suppose that $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $D=\text{Diag}(\mathbf{v}) $ is a diagonal matrix with $ \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb R^{n}$. Suppose that the first entry of $\mathbf{v}$ is denoted by $x$. I want to see if in general we can solve analytically for $x$ such that $AD$ has an eigenvalue equal to 1. If so, and if there are multiple solutions, is there a way to restrict the associated eigenvector strictly positive?
Context. I am working on a Expectation Maximization problem in which I have equivalent sets of potential latent variables and I am deciding on the most efficient choice of them in terms of computation speed. Part of the exercise is to see, given a set of latent variable values, how easily one can solve for the rest of them.
What have I tried? I know in general, we cannot say much about the eigenvalues of $AD$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$ and the elements of $D$. But my question can be much more specific: we know everything except one element of the diagonal $D$. I had in mind to use line search but I found no "monotonicity" to take advantage to make sure I converge to a solution. Also, I have no idea how to approach the multiplicity of the solutions. Even a hint on how to proceed can be helpful.

You are trying to solve a problem of the form $det(B+xC) = 0$, i.e. you want to solve a generalized eigenvalue problem that in general may have up to $n$ solutions

1 is an eigenvalue if and only if $\text{det}(AD - I) = 0$. By Laplace's expansion, this is a polynomial equation in $x$ of degree $1$: it is very easy to solve.

Notice that $A$ is invertible. Call $B = D(0) - A^{-1}$.
You want to know when $AD(x)$ has an eigenvalue 1, i.e. when
$$det(AD(x) - I) = det(A(D(x) - A^{-1}))= det(A(xe_1e_1^T + B)) =0$$
and notice that this is equivalent to ask  $ det(xe_1e_1^T + B) =0$ that is a polynomial in $x$ of degree 1 or 0, and since for $x=0$ it is equal to $det(B)$, then necessarily by Laplace
$$0 = det(xe_1e_1^T + B)=x \cdot det(\tilde B) + det(B),$$
where $\tilde B$ is obtained from $B$ by removing the first row and column.
From here we can conclude that

If $\tilde B$ is invertible, then the only solution is $x=-det(B)/det(\tilde B) = - 1/(B^{-1})_{1,1}$
If $B$ is invertible and $\tilde B$ is singular, then there is no solution
If $B$ and $\tilde B$ are singular, then all $x$ are solutions


Let $f(x) = \det(A D(x) - I)$. 1 is an eigenvalue of $A D(x)$ if and only if $f(x) = 0$. But $A D(x)-I$ is a matrix where $x$ appears only in the first column and the corresponding coefficients are degree 1 polynomials in $x$. By Laplace's expansion of the determinant it follows that $f(x)$ is a degree 1 polynomial, consequently
\begin{equation}
f(x) = (f(1)-f(0)) x + f(0)
\end{equation}
The equation $f(x) = 0$ is now very easy to solve.
